# How to fetch single post data from this Json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Json
React How to Fetch single post from this Json
I am trying to get single post using id..
I could not get single Post value
Anyone Please help me

```
export const fetchDetail = (id) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchDetailBegin());
        fetch(`http://localhost:3004/magazines/${id}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            if(res.error) {
                throw(res.error);
            }
            dispatch(fetchDetailSuccess(res));
            return res;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(fetchDetailError(error));
        })
    }
}

    { "magazine": 
        [
            { "id": 1, 
              "name": "Magazine Name 1", 
              "slug":"magazine_1", 
              "imgsrc": "couv1.jpg", 
              "data":[{"id": 1,"imgsrc": "1.jpg","page":1,"pagination": "C1"},{"id": 2,"imgsrc": "2.jpg","page":2,"pagination": "1"},{"id": 3,"imgsrc": "3.jpg","page":3,"pagination": "2"},{"id": 4,"imgsrc": "4.jpg","page":4,"pagination": "3"}, {"id": 5,"imgsrc": "5.jpg","page":3,"pagination": "2"},{"id": 6,"imgsrc": "6.jpg","page":6,"pagination": "5"},{"id": 7,"imgsrc": "7.jpg","page":7,"pagination": "6"},{"id": 8,"imgsrc": "8.jpg","page":8,"pagination": "7"}, {"id": 9,"imgsrc": "9.jpg","page":9,"pagination": "8"},{"id": 10,"imgsrc": "10.jpg","page":10,"pagination": "9"},{"id": 11,"imgsrc": "11.jpg","page":11,"pagination": "10"},{"id": 12,"imgsrc": "12.jpg","page":12,"pagination": "11"}, {"id": 13,"imgsrc": "13.jpg","page":13,"pagination": "12"},{"id": 14,"imgsrc": "14.jpg","page":14,"pagination": "13"},{"id": 15,"imgsrc": "15.jpg","page":15,"pagination": "14"}] }, { "id": 2, "name": "Magazine Name 2", "slug":"magazine_2", "imgsrc": "couv2.jpg", "data":[{"id": 1,"imgsrc": "1.jpg","page":1,"pagination": "C1"},{"id": 2,"imgsrc": "2.jpg","page":2,"pagination": "1"},{"id": 3,"imgsrc": "3.jpg","page":3,"pagination": "2"},{"id": 4,"imgsrc": "4.jpg","page":4,"pagination": "3"}, {"id": 5,"imgsrc": "5.jpg","page":3,"pagination": "2"},{"id": 6,"imgsrc": "6.jpg","page":6,"pagination": "5"},{"id": 7,"imgsrc": "7.jpg","page":7,"pagination": "6"},{"id": 8,"imgsrc": "8.jpg","page":8,"pagination": "7"}, {"id": 9,"imgsrc": "9.jpg","page":9,"pagination": "8"},{"id": 10,"imgsrc": "10.jpg","page":10,"pagination": "9"},{"id": 11,"imgsrc": "11.jpg","page":11,"pagination": "10"},{"id": 12,"imgsrc": "12.jpg","page":12,"pagination": "11"}, {"id": 13,"imgsrc": "13.jpg","page":13,"pagination": "12"},{"id": 14,"imgsrc": "14.jpg","page":14,"pagination": "13"},{"id": 15,"imgsrc": "15.jpg","page":15,"pagination": "14"}] },{ "magazine": [{ "id": 1, "name": "Magazine Name 1", "slug":"magazine_1", "imgsrc": "couv1.jpg", "data":[{"id": 1,"imgsrc": "1.jpg","page":1,"pagination": "C1"},{"id": 2,"imgsrc": "2.jpg","page":2,"pagination": "1"},{"id": 3,"imgsrc": "3.jpg","page":3,"pagination": "2"},{"id": 4,"imgsrc": "4.jpg","page":4,"pagination": "3"}, {"id": 5,"imgsrc": "5.jpg","page":3,"pagination": "2"},{"id": 6,"imgsrc": "6.jpg","page":6,"pagination": "5"},{"id": 7,"imgsrc": "7.jpg","page":7,"pagination": "6"},{"id": 8,"imgsrc": "8.jpg","page":8,"pagination": "7"}, {"id": 9,"imgsrc": "9.jpg","page":9,"pagination": "8"},{"id": 10,"imgsrc": "10.jpg","page":10,"pagination": "9"},{"id": 11,"imgsrc": "11.jpg","page":11,"pagination": "10"},{"id": 12,"imgsrc": "12.jpg","page":12,"pagination": "11"}, {"id": 13,"imgsrc": "13.jpg","page":13,"pagination": "12"},{"id": 14,"imgsrc": "14.jpg","page":14,"pagination": "13"},{"id": 15,"imgsrc": "15.jpg","page":15,"pagination": "14"}]
            },
            { "id": 2, 
              "name": "Magazine Name 2",
              "slug":"magazine_2",
              "imgsrc": "couv2.jpg",
              "data":[{"id": 1,"imgsrc": "1.jpg","page":1,"pagination": "C1"},{"id": 2,"imgsrc": "2.jpg","page":2,"pagination": "1"},{"id": 3,"imgsrc": "3.jpg","page":3,"pagination": "2"},{"id": 4,"imgsrc": "4.jpg","page":4,"pagination": "3"}, {"id": 5,"imgsrc": "5.jpg","page":3,"pagination": "2"},{"id": 6,"imgsrc": "6.jpg","page":6,"pagination": "5"},{"id": 7,"imgsrc": "7.jpg","page":7,"pagination": "6"},{"id": 8,"imgsrc": "8.jpg","page":8,"pagination": "7"}, {"id": 9,"imgsrc": "9.jpg","page":9,"pagination": "8"},{"id": 10,"imgsrc": "10.jpg","page":10,"pagination": "9"},{"id": 11,"imgsrc": "11.jpg","page":11,"pagination": "10"},{"id": 12,"imgsrc": "12.jpg","page":12,"pagination": "11"}, {"id": 13,"imgsrc": "13.jpg","page":13,"pagination": "12"},{"id": 14,"imgsrc": "14.jpg","page":14,"pagination": "13"},{"id": 15,"imgsrc": "15.jpg","page":15,"pagination": "14"}] 
            }
        ]
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the endpoint API handle returning responses by ID like that? or is the ID irrelevant in the request and you are receiving back an array of magazines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the api had an endpoint for fetching a single entity then you can request it by id.
If not then you can filter the results like so:

```
let post = res.magazine.find(post => post.id === id);
```

Comment: [array::find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) may be a better choice here to return just the magazine object versus an array.